# Посчитать количество определенных символов в текстовом файле, linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть есть большой файл с текстом, нужно подсчитать количество определенных символов, например Y, команды вроде

```
cat file_name |grep -c Y
```

считают только количество строк содержащих искомый символ, а необходимое полное количество символов

Comment: [Ответ на англоязычном SO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387656/how-to-count-the-times-a-specific-character-appears-in-a-file): `cat file_name |tr -cd 'Y' | wc -c`

Comment: `wc -m` - количество символов,  wc -c - количество байт

Answer (score 4):

## Вариант 1

```
cat file_name |tr -cd 'Y' | wc -m
```

tr команда для преобразования текста:

`-с` - получить символы не перечисленные в таблице

`-d` удалить символы

wc - считает байты, символы, слова.

`-m` -  считать символы, 
  `-с` -  байты
  `-w` - слова
  `-l` - строки

Хоть и с мусором, но вроде правильно

```
$ echo "ваваЭ" | tr -cd "в" | wc -m
2
$ echo "ваваЭ" | tr -cd "в" | wc -c
7
```

## Вариант 2

```
echo "агнан" | grep -o "н" | wc -l

grep -o выводит только совпадение, по одному на строку
```

Comment: По поводу `wc -m`. / А как сказать команде `tr`, что ее аргумент это *символы, а не байты*?

Comment: @avp интересный вопрос, но c -cd считает правильно =)

Comment: *Useless use of cat...*

Comment: @0andriy cat is useless by design)

Comment: @eri, посмотрел на поведение `tr`. К сожалению, она считает, что ее аргумент это **байты, а не символы** / `avp@avp-xubu2:~$ echo йжзи | tr -cd й | hexdump -C
 ==> 00000000  d0 b9 d0 d0 d0                                    |.....|
00000005
avp@avp-xubu2:~$ echo йжзи | tr -cd й | wc -m
 ==> 1
avp@avp-xubu2:~$` / Хотя `wc -m` и дает правильный ответ в данном примере, но я бы не поручился, что он будет правилен для *произвольного* файла  / Отразите это в update ответа?